# "and" in Author Name

Tags: bibtex

I was sure to find the answer to this rightaway, but somehow it didn't show up. I'm trying to add an organization as an author with "and" inside the name.
Like:

```
@MISC{secfindings,
    author = {Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC)},
}
```

this should show up as:
 Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC). (2011). etc...

I'm using the apacite package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
@MISC{secfindings,
    author = {{Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC)}},
}
```

in this case the author must be handled as one group.

Answer (score 8):

You can include name components in an additional set of braces to stop bibtex's processing. So, try `{{Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC)}}`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also define a string (useful for if you are going to have multiple sources (or repetitious uses) from the same "author."  For example:

```
@String { SEC = {{Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC)}} }
% Strings should be placed at the head of the *.bib file

@MISC {secfindings
    Author       = SEC,
    Institution  = SEC,
    Organization = SEC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Authorea.com, neither `{{A and B}}` nor `@String {AANDB = {{A and B}} }` worked for me. This did: `author = {A a{}n{}d B}`.

Comment: I assume `{A a{}nd B}` would have worked just as well.